# Advance analytics on the container logs which is present inside storage accountV2(append_blob )

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I sent my azure databricks logs to storage account & Microsoft by default contains those entry in append_blob. I tried to read the Json data with access key I got a error ( shaded.databricks.org.apache.hadoop.fs.azure.AzureException: com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Incorrect Blob type, please use the correct Blob type to access a blob on the server. Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual APPEND_BLOB).

Error - [image]

Is there any way to read directly that data path(insights-logs-jobs.mdd.blob.core.windows.net/resourceId=/SUBSCRIPTIONS/xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx/RESOURCEGROUPS/ssd--RG/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DATABRICKS/WORKSPACES/addd-PROCESS-xx-ADB/y%3D2021/m%3D12/d%3D07/h%3D00/m%3D00/PT1H.json")

Second way I tired to copy data to other container where data comes in block_blob & tried to read using databricks it works. But need to automate the copy data from multiple container to another. As seen in diagram.
[image]

Comment: what DBR version is used?

Comment: I tried on 7.3 and 8.3.

Comment: Looking at the above error message in the screenshot that you have shared. This error message occurs when you are trying to read the append blobs which is not supported in the windows azure storage blob file system.

Comment: As per the [Azure Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data-sources/wasb-check-blob-types), There is no workaround for this issue.
Use Azure CLI or Azure Storage SDK for Python to identify if the directory contains append blobs or the object is an append blob.
You can implement either a Spark SQL UDF or custom function using RDD API to load, read, or convert blobs using Azure Storage SDK for Python.

Comment: Do you have some UDF which will convert the blob mode automatically. Currently I have done copy activity to another container and reading it from data bricks. But Adf I wanted to create a one pipeline as mentioned in the step2.

Comment: Hello Venkatesh, It really rare we have option to send logs to storage account but when it comes to read the data tough time to get the data. No good article from the Microsoft also it there any way to approach the problem to Microsoft team.